# Laravel 4: Interating over array of objects

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel-4

I'm slowly learning Laravel/PHP and am building a menu system for a basic CMS.I have stored the menu in the database as json. This way I can use it for other apps etc.

I am trying to now decode the json and loop through it to display my menu. The new array is an array of objects. My question is:

• How can I iterate through this array? When I attempt to get $item->id it works fine. However, when I then try to get $item->title I get an ErrorException

I'm sure it is something simple. Its driving me nuts! Thanks for take the time to look...

#### Controller

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $view = View::make('admin.menus.edit');
    $view['seo_title'] = Lang::get('admin.system_name') . ' | Edit ' . Lang::choice('admin.menus', 1);
    $view['id'] = $id;
    $view['menu'] = Menus::find($id);
    $view['menuitems'] = json_decode($view->menu->menu_items);
    return $view;
}
```

#### View with foreach

```
    @foreach( $menuitems as $item)
    <h4>{{ $item->title }}</h4>
@endforeach
```

#### Json in menu_items col

```
[{"title":"Title","link":"/test.html","id":"1","children":[{"title":"Title","link":"/test.html","id":"2","children":[{"title":"Title","link":"/test.html","id":"3"}]}]},{"id":"4"},{"id":"5","children":[{"id":"6","children":[{"id":"7"}]}]},{"id":"8"},{"id":"9"}]
```

#### Object after json_decode

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object (
                        [title] => Title
                        [link] => /test.html
                        [id] => 1
                        [children] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object (
                                                                        [title] => Title
                                                                        [link] => /test.html
                                                                        [id] => 2 [children] => Array (
                                                                                                    [0] => stdClass Object (
                                                                                                    [title] => Title
                                                                                                    [link] => /test.html
                                                                                                    [id] => 3
                                                                                                    )
                                                                                                )
                                                                    )
                                            )
                        )

[1] => stdClass Object (
                        [id] => 4
                        )

[2] => stdClass Object (
                        [id] => 5
                        [children] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object (
                                                                        [id] => 6
                                                                        [children] => Array (
                                                                                            [0] => stdClass Object (
                                                                                            [id] => 7
                                                                                            )
                                                                                        )
                                                                    )
                                            )
                        )

[3] => stdClass Object (
                        [id] => 8
                        )

[4] => stdClass Object (
                        [id] => 9 
                        )
```

)

Thanks again - I hope someone can spot the error of my ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your json data only have a title for the first item. The title is undefined for the other menuitems, so you probably get a undefined property warning, when you try to access the undefined titles in your foreach loop.

You can check if there is a title in the loop

```
@foreach( $menuitems as $item)
    <h4>{{{ isset($item->title) ? $item->title : 'Default Title' }}}</h4>
@endforeach
```

Or you have to make sure, that every menuitem in your dataset (json) has a title property.

Comment: Ahhhh. Legend! I was starting to think that it was something to do with the data not being valid. Many thanks Dane. You have really helped.